# This is a comment, not an answer!

Tags: discussion, comment, flagging, answers

Sometimes comments get to long or someone wants to include pictures or low-rep user can't comment anywhere, so people decide to give a comment in the answer field.

If it is not useful/possible to convert it into a comment, is it be ok to turn this "answers" in CW mode, either by asking the answerer or a moderator to do it?

Comment: Regarding low-rep users and CW: it doesn't seem harmful to me if they accrue some reputation from these half-answers, if the posts are useful, so that they might reach 50 and then be able to comment.

Comment: I have to say that when I recently joined math.stackexchange, it confused me quite a bit when I found that I couldn't comment until I had acquired sufficient reputation. I just gave some "half-answers" while I was accruing the required reputation, but I think it would have saved me some head-scratching if it were made a bit clearer (in the faq?) if this is an acceptable thing to do ... or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Flag it for moderator attention. See [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4328/capture-the-flag-faq-on-flagging) recent meta question.

Also, flagging answers that should be comments was explicitly mentioned in [another recent meta thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4319/what-is-within-a-moderators-power-regarding-posts).

Comment: However, I do not think every such answer should be either turned CW or made a comment. Sometimes these side remarks may contain valuable related information.