# Is it no longer considered OK to post a comment of more than 600 characters as an answer?

Tags: discussion, comment, deletion

On more than one occasion, always with an explicit disclaimer, I
have posted a comment of more than 600 characters as an "answer".
I have done this because I have quite often seen other people do it, and
I have never once, in 5 years in Maths.SE, seen anyone object to the
practice. But a comment I posted in this way last night has been
deleted. The reason given was "low quality". (I have undeleted it,
but I have no idea if that action will remain in effect for long.)

Has there been a change in policy?

Or is there some other reason why this comment in particular was
singled out for deletion? Is it perhaps connected with there having
been a truly extraordinary comment thread on the question? The
thread - including the first comment, which had nothing to do with
the very strange dispute that suddenly erupted - was deleted in
its entirety, not even moved to chat (as I had requested, in order
to mitigate the extreme distraction from the question that had been
asked). That is something else that I have never seen happen in my 5
years in Maths.SE, and this coincidence seems highly unlikely to be
accidental.

[Timeline for answer to Is the sequence $(B_n)_{n \in \Bbb{N}}$ unbounded, where $B_n := \sum_{k=1}^n\mathrm{sgn}(\sin(k))$? by Calum Gilhooley - Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3739469/timeline).

Comment: I mean, if the long comment is full of profanity, definitely not. If the long comment is relevant, and helpful, then maybe. It's more of a case-by-case situation. I don't think we want a "catch all" policy here.

Comment: Personal I find those data very confusing. We are asking if $B_n$ is unbounded, but your data seems to be arguing that there are sub-sequence $B_{n_k}$ so that $B_{n_k}$ is bounded? Sorry but I don't see how your data could help answer the question. At least there is no explanations.

Comment: To those upvoting @ArcticChar's comment: I have already answered it in a stopgap comment on my disputed answer-cum-comment. [No, that was not a profanity, that was Latin. $\ \ddot\smile\ $ . Although on second thoughts it should probably have been *qua*.] That is the proper place for discussing it. It seems odd that no-one who cares so much about the proper answering of a mathematical question that they want to delete my improper answer has bothered to comment on either the question or my "answer". Curiouser and curiouser.

Comment: @Calum  If you want to comment in an answer field, due to the length of the comment, and you straight-out say, "Not an answer", then please mark your comment "community wiki", so you don't get rep for any upvotes, just like any comment does not earn rep for comment upvotes.

Comment: I don't think the practice of commenting in an answer field was every  strictly okay.  Just like answering PSQ's is controversial.  Just because you've seen others do it, and did it yourself, doesn't make it always okay to do.  So your premise "Is it no longer okay to ...", leads me to say "it hasn't been entirely okay for a long, long time".  Just because people do X, doesn't make doing X right.  All you see is what remains.  You don't see the tons of answers already deleted for doing what you misread as "okay".

Comment: This seems to be a case that somehow got out of control (one user even got suspended). My own take is that the joy of math should be able to offset other emotions which have come into play here. People involved here are far more mature (in terms of experience and academic knowledge) than me and  they should be able to observe that the question on main site and its answers were posted in good faith. IMHO the question is one which has a fairly simple statement but no easy answer (maybe an open problem). A cross posting on MO should help.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh It was heartening to read your comment, but I think it would be only fair to wait until after mathworker21 has returned from his suspension before considering cross-posting to MO.

Comment: Yeah we should definitely wait before cross posting on MO. Mathworker21 answer is already a great start and who knows the bounty placed may motivate others to attack the problem. But I do feel saddened by whatever happened in this case. Much worse than what happened in recent past in meta thread dealing with my actions (vote to close and answer a question simultaneously).

Comment: Is this post the reason this account is suspended temporarily?  Stack Exchange strikes again!

Comment: @tilper It is generally not safe to make assumptions about the reasons that moderators have suspended accounts, particularly when you do not have access to the full record. 
 By the way, there are, by my count, three accounts which were temporarily suspended in relation to this post.

Comment: @tilper: I don't think suspensions are due to this post, but they are perhaps due to some heated discussions in comments (which may have been deleted as well so I can't confirm).

Comment: @XanderHenderson: This also shows the gravity of the problem here. Discussions related to this post seem to have to gone to such a level where mods were forced to suspend 3 users to let them cool down. I don't know how mods might be feeling in such a situation.

Answer (score 21):

In the spirit of the question: This started life as more of an extended comment than an answer. I think it has morphed into an answer now though.

Math.SE seems to be based around the idea that every problem is soluble by a single person. This is clearly not the case, as, for example, in research mathematics single-authored papers are the exception rather than the normal. Providing an incomplete answer, for example by proving that the result does not hold for a large number of cases, or verifying that it does hold in many cases, should therefore not be discouraged (especially for hard questions); it may lead someone else to solving the problem, which is how collaboration works. This all requires effort and thought, and readers should be allowed to decide, in the usual way, whether or not the author should receive reputation for this partial answer; therefore, such answers should not be automatically made community wikis.

I see no reason why providing data, found via computation and confirming the result for a sufficiently large number of cases, does not fall under the above paragraph, provided it comes with supporting explanations. Computational results of this nature can be useful. Indeed, the journal [Experimental Mathematics](https://www.tandfonline.com/action/journalInformation?show=aimsScope&journalCode=uexm20) is essentially devoted to computation-led research. The [Ternary Goldbach Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_weak_conjecture) is a concrete result which relied on this sort of explicit computation. It's proof proceeded in two steps: 1) prove the result for all numbers bigger than a certain, known number $n$, and 2) use a computer to verify the result for all numbers less than $n$.

Comment: Math.se does not purport to be research level math. As you stated, you are aware that "Math.SE seems to be based around the idea that every problem is soluble by a single person. "

Comment: @amWhy to be fair, I think MSE does not purport to _not_ be research-level math either, as it is meant "for people studying math at any level".

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist I think the point amWhy wanted to convey is that not every type of question is a good fit for the format. One might phrase it as saying the site is not for engaging in mathematical research (on the site).

Comment: @user1720 SE is **not** "based around the idea that every problem is soluble by a single person"; what is true though is that SE does not pretend to be suitable for every type of mathematical inquiry, *only those* that fit into the format, which arguably can be paraphrased as can be answered by a single person in a few paragraphs. This is a healthy self-limitation.

Comment: @quid Thanks for the clarification. While I do agree that the site is designed with the expectation that answers have to have some sense of definitiveness to them (hence open-ended and opinion-based questions are off-topic), I do think there is value in partial answers that build towards a definitive one. Of course, as you say, just because it has value doesn’t mean it belongs *here*, but my feeling is that maybe it should. Admittedly, I don’t know how much room there is for opinion on this matter, so maybe my thoughts on this are moot.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist *partial* answers are actually alright.

Comment: @quid I fear we might differ on what qualifies as a partial answer then :)

Comment: You say that Math SE is "based around the idea that every problem is soluble by a single person."  I don't think that is quite right.  Rather, Math SE is built to answer only certain *kinds* of questions.  The questions that are most appropriate for Math SE are those which have authoritative answers, which can *typically* be provided by a single user in a couple of paragraphs.  There are *tons* of good questions in the world which would, nevertheless, be poor questions *here*, because they don't fit the format.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I don't know if what you're saying is true, i.e. if MSE is only for those types of questions, but I really, really, really hope it isn't. I think collaborating with others on difficult questions is very fun, and this website is a great place to do it.

Comment: If I see you frantically trying to pound screws in with a hammer, I am going to offer you a screwdriver.  You might enjoy pounding things in with a hammer, but it simply isn't the right tool for that job.  Collaboration is good, but Math SE is not designed for it.

Comment: @XanderHenderson You have put your finger on the problem, as you also did in the GENTLE chatroom on my one visit there. (It's not very active, so no-one should have any difficulty in finding our discussion, but I'll try to work out how to post a reference.) I'll briefly state my own opposing view (but this should really be for a separate Meta question): the key is *objectivity* of questions, not prediction in advance of their answerability. (Of course, if it is evident in advance that a question is of research level, it does not fit.) *That*, or so I believe, is the consensus of the community.

Comment: For example, Jaeseop Ahn's first question, [Alternating Harmonic Series Spin-off](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3731454), *might* have been a research level question (like the convergence of the [Flint Hills Series](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FlintHillsSeries.html)), for all that anybody knew at the time, but @mathworker21 provided a fully satisfactory answer to it. Must the status of a question's belonging or not belonging to this community be in a state of perpetual oscillation and suspension, according to the present state of work on it? Or can we have a bit more stability than that?

Comment: @CalumGilhooley : While we are discussing whether the questions are fit for MSE or MO, the MO people seem to be more lenient and often give good answers to well posed questions which are clearly not research level. But this is based on my far limited experience on MO.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh please don't encourage people to post non-research questions to MathOverflow. While *some* users there may post answers to such questions, I think more users are quick to vote to close, and really don't want to see such questions.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Well, I was not trying to do that. If my comment is being seen even as a slight endorsement for such behavior then I feel sorry for the same. The right way to decide whether questions are fit or not is through the democratic process of voting and in general one should avoid meta trials and heated arguments and instead use the vote and don't be so emotional about it.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh that starts to become a bit general but I feel strongly about that: Whether a question is on or off-topic is not decided by a democratic vote; it is decided via a collective evaluation carried out by users that are ideally informed by the policies in place.  There is a lot of gray-area and the evaluation is often subjective evaluations, but still ultimately users engaging  in community moderation are supposed to help implement the policies  of the site and should not take their personal opinion as their only criterion (I think it practical terms we do not disagree).

Comment: @quid: I fully agree with your remarks and but somewhere one has to draw a line while doing a collective evaluation. Suppose a group of people decide to close a question and another group decides to reopen. This matter is then discussed in meta, but then somehow it needs to be ensured that both the factions don't get into a war. After a certain point of expressing opinions one must stop and don't think about who wins or loses. And at that point mods can chip in if someone crosses the line. Imho the current case did not simply deserve to be blown out of proportions to reach this stage.

Comment: @quid: I think there is another issue at stake. While people can make good decisions most of the time then should also be ready to admit than there can be an error once in while and one should in that case introspect a bit rather than act defensive.

Comment: By the way re "I see no reason why providing data, found via computation and confirming the result for a sufficiently large number of cases, does not fall under the above paragraph, provided it comes with supporting explanations." It's not clear how that is relevant to the case at hand.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I agree that one should resist escalation. Related to this, I would like to point out that the initial action that this meta thread is about is so weak that the poster can undo it *all alone.* It's not a major thing to begin with. In any case the deletion at hand was not out of line. It was arguably on the rigid side of interpreting the guidelines, but it was not wrong either. There is a post that starts "Not an answer" and it gets deleted for being  "not an answer."  It's not clear why this needs to be that controversial.

Comment: @quid: when people put efforts into writing an answer then do get attached to it so they will not like it when it gets deleted. I think this can be handled by editing the post to make it as good as an answer can be (like "this is partial answer" ) and then undelete it. While that version may also get deleted by people who think otherwise, but then somewhere this has to stop. By the way I did a search on my answers and found that I have myself posted around 15 comments as answers as they were too long. After this meta thread I will be more careful in future.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: yes, it can also be handled by recording the information as a comment, or (what was proposed as compromise) turning the post into CW. There are various options. Indeed, one could also just have left it alone. What I find a bit puzzling is a position that seems to put the interests of the user that posted above everything else. Users that put effort into maintaining the interest of the site will not like it either when their efforts get under-cut.

Comment: @quid My answer was written to be more general, but with the case in hand in mind. At the time of writing, the partial answer which motivated the OP was data with no explanation. So it was falling below the level I was writing about.

Comment: @user1729 not only that but it did not confirm any cases at all. Every finite sequence is bounded. What it actually did was doing is to suggest that it light be unbounded and the growth might be doubly-logarithmic, IIRC, without saying so explicitly. That's something that is interesting yet could've been conveyed perfectly well in a comment, arguably it would even have been better if there'd been more explanation and less numbers. .

Comment: @quid: I think the effort of maintaining the site (including a large effort by CURED people to keep trash out and the effort of moderators) is something which must be respected at all costs. Only because of that we have a conducive environment to enjoy the forum. I also believe that the people involved in such efforts are capable enough to earn large amount of reps by answering yet they chose to put their energy into maintaining the site. It always pays to listen what they say even if one does not agree wholeheartedly with their views. Cont'd...

Comment: @quid: the goal in such meta discussions should be reach out to the other faction and opt for a happy compromise rather than ugly skirmish. If a question / answer gets closed / deleted there is always a way out to rectify it (improve it, add more stuff, post new question/answer) or to convince the other side

Comment: FWIW: i post questions on math.se often with no expectation they are solvable and therefore might expect multiple people/rounds to be needed. I think that is a trend that will increase as math is one a few subjects where one can very quickly hit the limits of the field (in any sufficiently obscure sub area) without mastery of most of the subject. And so most curious question askers will probably naturally end up becoming conjecture makers if not stopped.

Answer (score 10):

First I must point out that this question is somewhat unclear. What do you mean by "post a *comment* of more than 600 characters (...)"? (Emphasis mine.) If "comment" means that *I would post it in the comments below the question, but there is no space*, then obviously this has never been OK. It is even somewhat self-contradictory, considering the role that comments have.

By the development of the discussion, I take it you mean by "comment" just that it is not a complete answer, and I'll assume this to be the case for my answer.

This is somewhat tricky. The short answer is: it depends on how useful the answer is.

The long answer is that in general, the network allows (and wants) answers to be useful and relevant. It is the case that in Mathematics those two are heavily correlated with correctness and completeness. So the "safest" way to make a useful answer is just to make a complete and correct answer. Others which usually can also be OK can be summarized in "partial" and "incomplete", and I'll clarify the distinction I make. (The way I use the terms may be nonstandard, which is why I'm clarifying.)

By "partial answers" I mean answers that solve a problem considering some simplifying hypotheses. For example, a question which asks "Is every foo a bar?" can have a useful answer "If the foo is also a xyzzy, then this holds because of (...)". How useful that is obviously depends on the question, on the restriction and the context, and will be evaluated by the community. (E.g., if someone asks "Is every continuous real function $f$ on $[0,1]$ integrable", then responding it with "Yes if we assume it to be constant" is obviously not useful. )

By "incomplete answers" I mean answers which make significant progress towards a solution but do not quite manage to close it up. Again, how useful that is will depend on the question, the context and will be evaluated by the community.

Those kinds of answers *can be* OK. Again, it depends and will be evaluated by the community. As always, these evaluations can be contested by the community. Preferably, all this should happen in a reasonable way, no matter how outrageous one thinks something is.

If an "answer" is not any of those, then it will usually be the case that it is not even an answer. And answers should be answers. (I know this sounds facetious, but there is no simpler way to put it. There is a flag for something being "Not an answer" for a reason.) So it is most likely not OK to post "something" as an answer which is not a complete and correct answer, or a partial answer, or an incomplete answer. (There may be exceptions, but I cannot think of one.) For example, we frequently delete things posted as "answers" that are questions about other answers, or corrections about other answers etc.

Now, turning to the specific case of your answer. The first version of your answer is not a complete and correct answer, not a partial answer and not an incomplete answer. (As per what I defined above.) This already points to it being potentially not useful. But more specifically, it was just some computations. It is entirely reasonable to be considered not an answer, and as such, should have been flagged as such and elaborated upon or deleted. To be honest, I say this almost objectively.

Comment: For clarity, is this answer (a) representative of the moderating team's collective policy, (b) representative of your policy as a moderator (i.e. it indicates how you will moderate as an individual moderator), (c) the *opinion* of the moderating team, or (d) your opinion as an individual user / moderator?

Comment: @Xander (b) and (d).

Comment: I second this. I'd stress that it is possible to post two comments in case one is too short. There can be rare reasons why an answer-box is really needed for technical reasons in which case one may consider an exception; the current case is maybe close to that, but this should have been stressed more.

Comment: Thirded. It seems like this may also be (c).

Answer (score -3):

**The answer box is meant for answers, not comments.**

The Stack Exchange model is meant to facilitate the construction of a high-quality database of questions and authoritative answers.  Stack Exchange is not a [social networking site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65261/is-stack-overflow-a-social-networking-site), nor is it a site for [collaboration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141508/how-can-stack-overflow-be-used-as-a-collaborative-tool) or [discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195954/where-can-i-ask-an-open-discussion-question).  On the Stack Exchange network, the "Answer" box is for answers.  It is not meant for long comments.

It is suggested elsewhere that if an answer is really just a long comment, then it ought to be [marked "Community Wiki"](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4353), though it is worth noting that there is an implicit assumption here that "not an answers" are a problem, i.e. they should not be treated as normal answers (they should either be converted to comments, or marked CW).  There was also an attempt to [discuss this issue](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2991/rfc-social-norm-about-not-an-answer-just-too-long-for-a-comment-and-communit), but little discussion actually followed.

It may also be worthwhile to read through my question about whether or not it is acceptable to [leave hints as answers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28969/is-it-acceptable-to-leave-hints-as-answers).  The consensus here appears to be that hints are fine, *as long as they lead to an answer*.  The extended comments-as-answers under discussion here don't even rise to that level—the answerers themselves don't even know if their comments will lead to an answer.

My conclusion is that the consensus leans towards the following statement:

> If your answer is really a long comment, then it shouldn't be posted as an answer.  If you *must* post your long comment in an answer box, then you should, at the very least, (a) clearly note that the answer is not an answer, and (b) mark your "answer" Community Wiki.

I originally said that, in light of the above, it was appropriate to delete [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/3739469/1) (note that I am linking to a particular version of that answer).  It was remarked by [KReiser](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54829596#54829596) that this might have sounded harsh, which was not my intention, so let me try to rephrase:  the original version of the answer consisted of a table of data, which was *interesting*, but didn't really answer the question.  It very much *was* an extended comment.  As such, I am sympathetic to the [users who voted to delete it](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/1413331).  An equally reasonable outcome (in my mind) would have been for the answerer to mark the answer as "Community Wiki".  The best possible outcome would be for the answerer to expand their remarks, as they have done.

Comment: (-1)You seriously *disapprove* of people working together *towards* an answer, making partial contributions, which quite often and entirely naturally are too long to fit into 600 characters? I am of entirely the opposite opinion. I frequently upvote other people's partial answers or extended useful comments. It's all part of doing mathematics. It all works pretty well, even though it is not a perfect fit for a rigid Q&A format. Most people seem to appreciate these sentiments. And of course *most* of the time there is no need for long comments or partial answers. Which is great when it happens.

Comment: That's the intent of Community Wiki, Collaboration.

Comment: @CalumGilhooley I have presented an answer which, to the best of my ability, reports the *consensus of the community*.  The phrase "You seriously *disapprove*..." is an implicit attack against my sincerity and my desire to discuss this issue in good faith.  I would be happy to discuss this, but I am not going to reply further to someone who accuses me of lying or otherwise misrepresenting my opinions.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I have been careful not to engage with you, but I must ask you what you mean by "Stack Exchange is not a [...] site for collaboration [...]", which seemed, and still seems, clear and unambiguous (and extremely narrow, dogmatic, and overly rigid) to me. I must also insist that you desist from doing exactly what you and amWhy have accused me of doing. I have never once questioned your sincerity or good faith, or accused you of lying, or intentionally misrepresented your opinions. Meanwhile, *you* and amWhy *have* accused *me* of a string of character flaws. Pause and reflect.

Comment: I also think you are mistaken in your (evidently sincere) belief that your actions represent the consensus of the community. Rather, I think you are pushing one particular opinion, to an extreme degree (and you are encouraged in doing this, by amWhy in particular, and no doubt also by several others who broadly agree with you). Of course, I could also be mistaken in my own sincere belief. I'm not great at judging consensus.

Comment: @CalumGilhooley In just this comment thread, you have accused me of insincerity, narrow dogmatism, and being unable to think for myself.  The worst that I have done is accuse you of being condescending, for which I *apologized* (and all of those comments have been deleted, anyway).  I would be happy to engage with you, but not before you cease these personal attacks.